# Optional.ofNullable orElse throws NPE

Tags: java, java-8, null, option-type

I have been working with this code :

```
Event rEvent = new Event();

Map<Long, Message> msgMap = getMsg();
Message msg = msgMap.get(rEvent.getMsgId());

Long id = Optional.ofNullable(rEvent.getPkId()).orElse(msg.getPkId());
```

Assume `rEvent.getPkId()` and msg are both `null`.
So `Optional.ofNullable(rEvent.getPkId())` will skipped, then `orElse` is executed. Here it throws `NPE`.
How to recode this using `Optional.ofNullable` for multiple null checks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply use a simple if else in your case:

```
Long id = null; // default value
if(rEvent.getPkId() != null) {
   id = rEvent.getPkId();
} else if(msg != null){
   id = msg.getPkId();
}
```

---

But if you want to practice `Optional`, in this case you need another `Optional` for `msg`:

```
Long message = Optional.ofNullable(msg)
        .map(Message::getPkId)
        .orElse(null);// default value OR:
        //.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Pk Id shouldn't be null."))

Long id = Optional.ofNullable(rEvent.getPkId()).orElse(message);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Assume rEvent.getPkId() is null and msg also null. So
> Optional.ofNullable(rEvent.getPkId()) will skipped, then orElse is
> executed. Here it throws null pointer exception. **How to recode this
> using Optional.ofNullable for multiple null checks**?

If the message is null you need to check beforehand. Considered the following method:

```
public static Long ofNullable(Long ...options){
   return Arrays.stream(options).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().orElseThrow();
}
```

which in your case :

```
Long messageID = (msg != null) ? msg.getPkId() : null;
Long id = ofNullable(rEvent.getPkId(), option2, .. option N -1, messageID);
```

We check first is the `msg` is null if it is we still used in the method `ofNullable` because it might happen that other options are not null and therefore can be used instead.

**Running Example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println(ofNullable(null, null, null, null));
    }catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        System.out.println("Ups every options is null!");
    }
    System.out.println(ofNullable(null, null, null, 10L));
    System.out.println(ofNullable(null, null, 3L));
    System.out.println(ofNullable(null, 2L, 3L));
    System.out.println(ofNullable(1L, 2L, 3L));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Ups every options is null!
10
3
2
1
```